# What are different methods to connect to Hive with Java other than JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, hive, spring-data-jpa

What are the different ways to connect Hive with Java other than JDBC? I want to connect to Hive of server one and select all data and dump it to the Hive of server two.

1. Can I use the spring boot with spring data jpa for the purpose.
2. What is the best way to achieve this and should we use spring batch for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [DistCP](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/tools/DistCp.html) for cluster to cluster copying.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: DistCP is an option but here its not allowed here for some restriction and hence we trying to use Java